# Advantage of PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, powershell

I don't really clearly understand what benefit of PowerShell can be used in relation to SP 2013?
What concrete example can it provide business value?

Answer (score 4):

To administer SharePoint 2013 without using PowerShell is possible, but you are limited to the use of the GUI of Central Administration, SharePoint Designer and Site Settings. There are a number of features that you simply can't use without running PowerShell because there is no GUI support for those features.

PowerShell is also used to automate processes, and tedious work as updating properties on SharePoint items. Currently I'm changing all my Pages libraries to pages libraries. All 2600+ of them. It can be done with Site Settings as well, but it will take a month to do it. My customer are not willing to pay for a month of work that can be done in ten hours. That's business value.

> Windows PowerShell is a command-line shell and scripting language that **provides an administrator full access** to applicable application programming interfaces (**APIs**). Administrators **can interact directly** with SharePoint 2013 to manipulate web applications, site collections, sites, lists and much more. In addition, an administrator can script cmdlets (pronounced "command-lets").

Reference: [Use Windows PowerShell to administer SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx)

Comment: I went on a Google search to try and find a list of all the cmdlets that perform tasks for which there is no GUI equivalent. Came up empty handed, though.

Comment: @RobertKaucher I did the same, but I've encountered this phenomena in several occasions. Maybe I'd start that list on a Community Wiki page? :-)

Comment: Done. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72038/what-are-the-cmdlets-for-sharepoint-2013-that-have-no-gui-equivalent

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Benny's response. In addition a lot of times we will write a script to do a task, this task is then tested in our test enviroment. Doing everything via a powershell script ensures that when it is put into production, it will be done the same way as was tested in our test enviroment. Thus reducing the possibility for human error.