# What are the cmdlets for SharePoint 2013 that have no GUI equivalent?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I've not found a comprehensive list on anywhere of the PowerShell cmdlets for SharePoint 2013 whose function or output cannot be achieved via the GUI (Central Admin, Site Settings, etc). I would consider these highly important for both IT Pros and Devs.

What are the PowerShell cmdlets that have no GUI equivalent in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: +1 Interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The most obvious non-GUI is creating the GUI itself. GUI, in this case, Central Administration, is created via the PowerShell cmdlet [New-SPCentralAdministration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607841.aspx).
- Creating (and most of the maintenance duties for) host named site collections is done entirely in PowerShell. [Chapter 1.2](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145376954.do)
- Create the Subscription Settings service, which is needed to enable Apps for SharePoint. [New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607823.aspx)
- Create new proxy groups aren't supported in Central Administration. Instead you need to use the New-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup cmdlet. [Chapter 3.2](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145376954.do)
- Import Signing Certificate for federation between SharePoint and ADFS, is not GUI supported. `$signcert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("<path to signing cert>")`  [Chapter 2.1](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145376954.do)
- Configure server to server (S2S) trust between two SharePoint farms, SharePoint and Lync or SharePoint and MS Exchange. [Chapter 2.1](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145376954.do)

Reference: [Exam Ref 70-331: Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145376954.do)

Answer (score 3):

Few which come immediately to mind:

1) Create Host Named Site Collections.

2) Request Management Administration

3) Convert Web Application from Classic Authentication to Claims.

3) Create Web Application with Classic Authentication.

Comment: Can add most of the configuration of a Search Service Application to the list